# implement Zoom in/out in android camera preview

Tags: android, camera, zooming

I am using this as an example and it works nice (camera api, not camera2): http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/hardware/camera-hardware/android-camera-example/

But, how can I implement zoom in/out using two buttons like + and - ?!?
Already searched for hours and nothing yet.

Thank you very much.

Comment: camera2 api (api 21 and higher) or for camera api?

Comment: camera api
my app is for api 14 +

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, it should be helpful:-

```
  case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                  if (mode == ZOOM) {
                    float newDist = spacing(event);

                    double zoomDist = newDist-oldDist;

                    if(zoomDist > 0){
                        if(zoomDist > 50 && zoomDist <= 200){

                            if (curZoomLevel < mZoomMax && gestureZoom == 0) {
                                gestureZoom ++;
                                GestureZoomIn();
                            }

                        }else if(zoomDist > 200 && zoomDist <= 300){


                            if (curZoomLevel < mZoomMax && gestureZoom == 1) {

                                gestureZoom ++;
                                GestureZoomIn();
                            }
                        }else if(zoomDist > 300 && zoomDist <= 400){

                            if (curZoomLevel < mZoomMax && gestureZoom == 2) {

                                gestureZoom++;
                                GestureZoomIn();
                            }

 //zoomin   
     private void GestureZoomIn(){
           if (mParameters.isZoomSupported()){
                mZoomMax = mParameters.getMaxZoom();
                if (zoom_text_value<mZoomMax) {
                    zoom_text_value++;
                    curZoomLevel++;
                    zoom_float=zoom_float+0.5;
                    onZoomValueChanged(curZoomLevel);

 //zoomout   
    private void GestureZoomOut(){
           if (mParameters.isZoomSupported()){

                if (0<zoom_text_value) {
                    zoom_text_value--;
                    curZoomLevel--;
                    zoom_float=zoom_float-0.5;
                    onZoomValueChanged(curZoomLevel);
```

Thanks

Comment: should you implement this on your surfaceview and would that also taken affect on the pictures you take when you zoom?