# Android studio: I need to implement a zoom in functionality to my camera app

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

The preview is showing but when I click zoom in or out nothing happens. Here is the code
This is the xml for the main activity
activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:onClick="captureImage"
        android:text="Capture" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:text="Gallery" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="686dp">

    </FrameLayout>

    <ZoomControls
        android:id="@+id/zoomControls"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="104dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-4dp" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the code in java for the MainActivity
MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.mycustomcamera;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;
    public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO = 2;

    String currentPhotoPath = null;
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    Camera camera;
    FrameLayout frameLayout;
    ShowCamera showCamera;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        frameLayout = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.frameLayout);
        Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                camera.takePicture(null, null, mPictureCallBack);
            }
        });
        //open the camera
        camera = camera.open();
        showCamera = new ShowCamera(this,camera);
        frameLayout.addView(showCamera);
    }

    Camera.PictureCallback mPictureCallBack = new Camera.PictureCallback()
    {
        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera)
        {
            File picture_file = getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
            if(picture_file == null)
            {
                Log.d(TAG, "Error creating media file, check storage permissions");

                return;
            }
            else
                {
                    try
                    {
                        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(picture_file);
                        fos.write(data);
                        fos.close();
                        //sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
                        //camera.startPreview();

                        //galleryAddPic();
                    }
                    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
                    {
                    Log.d(TAG, "File not found: " + e.getMessage());
                    }
                    catch (IOException e)
                    {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Error accessing file: " + e.getMessage());
                     }
                    camera.startPreview();
                    //camera.stopPreview();
                    //camera.release();

                }
        }
    };

    /** Create a file Uri for saving an image or video */
    private static Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(int type){
        return Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile(type));
    }

    /** Create a File for saving an image or video */
    private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type){
        // To be safe, you should check that the SDCard is mounted
        // using Environment.getExternalStorageState() before doing this.

        File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "MyCustomCamera");
        // This location works best if you want the created images to be shared
        // between applications and persist after your app has been uninstalled.

        // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
        if (! mediaStorageDir.exists()){
            if (! mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
                Log.d("MyCustomCamera", "failed to create directory");
                return null;
            }
        }

        // Create a media file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        File mediaFile;
        if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE){
            mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
                    "IMG_"+ timeStamp + ".jpg");
        } else if(type == MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
            mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
                    "VID_"+ timeStamp + ".mp4");
        } else {
            return null;
        }

        return mediaFile;
    }


    private void galleryAddPic()
    {
        Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
        File f = new File(currentPhotoPath);
        Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
        mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
        this.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
    }







}
```

This is the code in java for the camera preview
ShowCamera.java

```
package com.example.mycustomcamera;

import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.Surface;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.ZoomControls;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

public class ShowCamera extends SurfaceView implements
        SurfaceHolder.Callback
{
    private static final String TAG = " => Main Activity: ";
    private SurfaceHolder holder;
    private Camera mcamera;
    private Context mContext;
    int currentZoomLevel = 0;
    int maxZoomLevel = 0;
    ZoomControls zoomControls;



    public ShowCamera(Context context, Camera camera)
    {
        super(context);
        mContext = context;
        this.mcamera = camera;
        holder = getHolder();
        holder.addCallback(this);
        holder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

    }


    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder)
    {
        if(mcamera == null) return;
        try
        {
            mcamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
            mcamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            mcamera.startPreview();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "Blad wlaczania podgladu kamery: " + e.getMessage());
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {


        if (holder.getSurface() == null) {
            return;
        }
        try {
            mcamera.stopPreview();
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
        Camera.Parameters params = mcamera.getParameters();
        List<Camera.Size> sizes = params.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
        Camera.Size optionalSize = getBestPreviewSize(width, height);
        params.setPreviewSize(optionalSize.width, optionalSize.height);

        mcamera.setParameters(params);

        Display display = ((WindowManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
        switch (display.getRotation()) {
            case Surface.ROTATION_0:
                mcamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_90:
                mcamera.setDisplayOrientation(0);
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_180:
                mcamera.setDisplayOrientation(270);
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_270:
                mcamera.setDisplayOrientation(180);
                break;
        }

        try {
            mcamera.setParameters(params);
            mcamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            mcamera.startPreview();


        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Blad wlaczania podgladu kamery" + e.getStackTrace());
        }


        ZoomControls zoomControls = (ZoomControls) findViewById(R.id.zoomControls);

        if (params.isZoomSupported()) {
            maxZoomLevel = params.getMaxZoom();

            try {

                zoomControls.setIsZoomInEnabled(true);
                zoomControls.setIsZoomOutEnabled(true);

                zoomControls.setOnZoomInClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        if (currentZoomLevel < 500) {
                            currentZoomLevel++;
                            mcamera.startSmoothZoom(currentZoomLevel);
                        }
                    }
                });

                zoomControls.setOnZoomOutClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        if (currentZoomLevel > 0) {
                            currentZoomLevel--;
                            mcamera.startSmoothZoom(currentZoomLevel);
                        }
                    }
                });
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        } else {
            zoomControls.hide();
        }

    }
        @Override
        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder)
        {
            mcamera.release();
            mcamera = null;
        }

        private Camera.Size getBestPreviewSize(int width, int height) {
        Camera.Size result = null;
        Camera.Parameters p = mcamera.getParameters();
        for (Camera.Size size : p.getSupportedPreviewSizes()) {
            if (size.width <= width && size.height <= height) {
                if (result == null) {
                    result = size;
                } else {
                    int resultArea = result.width * result.height;
                    int newArea = size.width * size.height;

                    if (newArea > resultArea) {
                        result = size;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    }
```

This is the manifest
AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.mycustomcamera">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyCustomCamera">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.example.android.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/paths"></meta-data>
        </provider>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: This might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32317300/implement-zoom-in-out-in-android-camera-preview

Comment: it absolutely doesn't. There is literally 0 explanation on what it does or how to implement it. Also since there is no full code to it.